# Binding Raylib's GetMousePosition() to Lua, causes memory leak [Lua C API]

Tags: c, lua

I have a function that gets the current mouse position on the screen using Raylib's GetMousePosition(). This is stored in a Vector2 variable, and a Lua table is created to store the 'x' and 'y' values of the Vector2.

However, each time the function is called in a Lua script, a new table is created, which means more and more memory is being used up (roughly 45kb to 95kb in a second), which forces the Lua garbage collector to work more often to free the unused Lua tables.

How should I modify this function so that it deallocates/frees the old table from memory, and then allocates a new one to store the x and y positions?

```
static int lua_getmouseposition(lua_State *L) {

Vector2 *mousePosition = MemAlloc(sizeof(Vector2));

if (mousePosition == NULL) {
    MemFree(mousePosition);
    return luaL_error(L, " GetMousePos error: out of memory \n");
}

*mousePosition = GetMousePosition();

lua_newtable(L);
// push x value to the table
lua_pushstring(L, "x");
lua_pushnumber(L, mousePosition->x);
lua_settable(L, -3);

// push y value to the table
lua_pushstring(L, "y");
lua_pushnumber(L, mousePosition->y);
lua_settable(L, -3);

lua_pop(L, -3);

MemFree(mousePosition);

return 1;
}
```

I tried using lua_pop to get rid of the table when I'm done with it, and I also use Raylib's MemFree() to get rid of old mouse position data. But the memory leak is still prevalent.

The lua script looks like this:

```
while not WinShouldClose() do
begin()
    cls(0, 0, 0) -- clear the screen, with a certain color
    
    pos = GetMousePos()
    
    -- draw the player (rectangle/square)
    DrawImage(sprite, pos1.x, pos1.y)
    
    playerInput()

    displayInfo()
    
stop()
end
```

The memory usage goes from 45 kilobytes to 95 kilobytes in less than a second, the Lua garbage collector automatically frees the unused table once memory usage reaches 95 kilobytes. Only for memory usage to rapidly rise again.

(In the C snippet i provided earlier, I ommitted some other Raylib function bindings like WinShouldClose(), and such, I verified that these functions are not the culprit, and work as expected.)

Any help is greatly appreciated :>

Comment: What does `lua_pop(L, -3);` mean?

Comment: Do not create a new table, reuse the existing one instead.